# Patching with a new host rule removes old set host rules in urlMaps API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a new host rule abc.xyz. And I want this to be appended to existing host rules.However when I try adding this to Host Rule, It removes the existing host rules.

Used PATCH API  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/patch

```
$host = "abc.xyz";
$hostRule = new \Google_Service_Compute_HostRule();
$hostRule->setPathMatcher($pathMatcherName);
$hostRule->setHosts([$host]);
```

Expected abc.xyz to be appended to my existing host rules pqr.stu. However abc.xyz is sen and pqr.stu is removed

Comment: Would you pleasetell me the exact command syntax and api you are using when the issue happens?

Comment: Do you plan to modify the existing rule, or just add one more?